# Implement with minimum CSS code

Tags: html, css, division

I want to implement the picture with minimum CSS code...
what should I do?

[image]

Comment: please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: create table. give color to particular td that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without javascript you can do it like this

```
<style>
    .row {
        width: 250px;
    }   
    .divSquare {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        float: left;
    }   
    .red {
        background-color: red;
    }   
    .blue {
        background-color: blue;
    }   
    .green {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="divSquare red"></div>
        <div class="divSquare blue"></div>
        <div class="divSquare red"></div>
        <div class="divSquare blue"></div>
        <div class="divSquare red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="divSquare blue"></div>
        <div class="divSquare green"></div>
        <div class="divSquare blue"></div>
        <div class="divSquare green"></div>
        <div class="divSquare blue"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="divSquare red"></div>
        <div class="divSquare blue"></div>
        <div class="divSquare red"></div>
        <div class="divSquare blue"></div>
        <div class="divSquare red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="divSquare blue"></div>
        <div class="divSquare green"></div>
        <div class="divSquare blue"></div>
        <div class="divSquare green"></div>
        <div class="divSquare blue"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could optimise this even more by giving the `.divSquare` a default colour of say red. Then you only need blue and green classes to overwrite the default.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum CSS? I think since you can't have less than no CSS a solution without any CSS would be your absolute minimum.

So here it is, courtesy of the good old days of horrible web programming ;)

```html
<table width="250" height="200" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#ff00ff"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#0000ff"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#ff00ff"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#0000ff"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#ff00ff"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#0000ff"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#00ff00"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#0000ff"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#00ff00"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#0000ff"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#ff00ff"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#0000ff"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#ff00ff"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#0000ff"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#ff00ff"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#0000ff"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#00ff00"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#0000ff"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#00ff00"></table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50" height="50" bgcolor="#0000ff"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using linear gradient.

```css
body {
  background:  
              linear-gradient(45deg, blue 25%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 26%), linear-gradient(225deg, blue 25%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 26%),
              linear-gradient(45deg, green 25%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 26%), linear-gradient(225deg, green 25%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 26%),
              linear-gradient(45deg, magenta 25%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 26%), linear-gradient(225deg, magenta 25%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 26%),
              linear-gradient(45deg, blue 25%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 26%), linear-gradient(225deg, blue 25%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 26%);
              
  background-position: 0 0,    25px 25px, 25px 50px, 100px 75px,
                       0 25px, 25px 50px, 25px 75px, 100px 100px;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```